# Getting 400 error with multiple request in jmeter with multiple BZM-Arrival threads group

Tags: jmeter

"I incorporated multiple API requests that depend on previous APIs within different BZM-arrival thread groups. However, upon executing these concurrent threads, a significant number of 400 errors were encountered. Interestingly, when executing the individual threads with the same APIs, a 200 response code was consistently received."

Please share the solution

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Status 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) means that your request is not valid

Given dependency on the previous response my expectation is your [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) fail to extract the data from the previous response as the server gets overloaded and returns an error instead of the anticipated response.

The next request uses JMeter variable placeholder like `${this one}` instead of the real value and hence request fails.

I would recommend temporarily enable [saving response data](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-data-in-jmeter) and re-running your test. Once done open your .jtl results file using [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and inspect what was wrong with the response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
In this case, I'm running APIs in two slaves and one master device is controlling it. And one API is dependent on the second one, here what happening is after running the one API in the first slave, the same API with the same data is running in the second slave and which is throwing the 400 error, because the data I'm passing in the second slave is wrong.

Comment: And a total of 12 APIs are here, If I run the first 6 APIs on a thread and run the cases there won't be any error, similarly f I run the second 6 APIs on a thread and run the cases there won't be any error. So I think the distribution of APIs is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

400 Bad request( Invalid Request )

Here is one possibility to consider:

1. Dependency on previous API responses: If some of your API requests depend on responses from previous requests, it is crucial to ensure proper synchronization and sequencing of requests. If concurrent threads are not properly coordinated, it is possible that subsequent requests are made before the required data is available from previous requests.

This can lead to corrupted or incomplete requests, resulting in 400 errors. Make sure you are handling dependencies correctly and waiting for necessary responses before proceeding with dependent requests.

Answer (score 0):

Being that you are getting `200` responses with individual requests but a high number of `400` server errors with requests using the [Arrivals Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ArrivalsThreadGroup/) there are a few things that can be the culprit and would recommend a troubleshooting sequence as follows:

- Compare the requests in your load test and ensure that there are no discrepancies or typos between the one you are getting the `200` response on, and the ones in your test that generate `400` responses.
- Ensure that any variables or other ways you are using to create your requests dynamically do not result in an invalid or malformed request.
- Ensure that the machine (or VM) that you are using to run your high-volume JMeter test from has the resources to run without running intp CPU, memory, or other system resource problems.  If JMeter is running out of resources, your requests may be malformed.
- Understand that the Arrivals Thread Group works differently from most other thread groups in that you define a *rate* for generating requests that continuously increases.  An extremely high request volume can result in running out of resources either on the machine running JMeter or the target test application and may result in `400` errors.  There is a good post [here](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2023/06/arrivals-thread-group/) which explains how the Arrivals Thread Group works in that way.